# Options for stopping sharing of records to partner org from business rules

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

What are my options when I want to stop sharing of records when some or all business rules have been met?  Like, is it possible for me to stop sharing when fields have been filled out by the partner connection? 
I see that the fields ConnectionSentId & ConnectionReceivedId have been deprecated since v15 of the API, and there is now an object called PartnerNetworkRecordConnection that handles the sharing.  Would I just create a class that handles queries to this object and updates the sharing status?  to do this is a code-only solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to map the fields from the partner org to your org, they then would propagate the field changes back to your org. At that time, you could run a trigger to check if the data had met your criteria, and if so delete the [PartnerNetworkRecordConnection](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partnernetworkrecordconnection.htm) record related to that record.